# Delphi android strings file localization

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am doing a lot of Android apps using Delphi Seattle but the biggest problem for me is the localization. I have tried the `DKLang` package but I prefer avoiding 3rd party component. I need to be able to translate my application in english, italian and french.

Under android studio ide (it uses java and xml) I am able to add folders with a suffix that indicates the country:

```
res/
    values-en/
        strings.xml
    values-it/
        strings.xml
    values-fr/
        strings.xml
```

In Delphi I have used the **Deployment manager** to add the 3 folders above and I also have the strings.xml files. Each of them has the translations that I need.

---

I cannot understand how to load the values inside the strings.xml in a `TLabel`. Is there a particular class for this? Do I have to do it at runtime?

The strings.xml files are structured like this:

```
//values-en/strings.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    
    <string name="title">Congruences</string>       
</resources>

//values-it/strings.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    
    <string name="title">Congruenze</string>       
</resources>
```

Basically the name is an identifier and then the word inside the tag is the translation. I have seen that I can use this:
                              //  file xml , file type
    TAndroidHelper.GetResourceID('strings', 'string');

I have no idea on how I can load the information at runtime. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's too much complicated to load the values inside the strings.xml (but it's possible), and it's not really the delphi way. In delphi what you can do instead is to use **TLang**

below the sample of the unit i use to translate

```
unit loki_Translation;

interface

uses system.classes,
     Fmx.controls,
     AlStringList,
     Win_definition;

function loki_translate(const AText: string): string;
function loki_SetLang(aLanguage: Twin_language): TALNVStringListU;

var
  vloki_CurrLang: TALNVStringListU;

implementation

uses FMX.Types,
     FMX.consts,
     system.SysUtils,
     alCommon,
     alString,
     WinDT_definition,
     loki_main;

{*****************************************************}
function loki_translate(const AText: string): string;
var idx: integer;
begin
  Idx := vloki_CurrLang.IndexOfName(AText);
  if Idx >= 0 then
    Result := vloki_CurrLang.ValueFromIndex[Idx]
  else
    Result := AText;
end;

{******************************************************************}
function loki_SetLang(aLanguage: Twin_language): TALNVStringListU;

  {$REGION 'ENU'}
  procedure _initENU;
  begin

    vloki_CurrLang.Add('_loki=loki');
    vloki_CurrLang.Add('_Exit_Application=Exit Application');
    vloki_CurrLang.Add('_AreYouSure=Are you sure?');
    vloki_CurrLang.Add('_Cancel=Cancel');
    vloki_CurrLang.Add('_OK=OK');
    vloki_CurrLang.Add('_Yes=Yes');
    vloki_CurrLang.Add('_speakx=Speak %s');
    vloki_CurrLang.Add('_and=and');

  end;
  {$ENDREGION}

{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
var i: integer;
{$ENDIF}

begin

  //init vloki_CurrLang
  ALfreeandnil(vloki_CurrLang);
  vloki_CurrLang := TALNVStringListU.Create;
  if aLanguage = ENU then _initENU;
  vloki_CurrLang.Duplicates := TDuplicates.Duperror;
  vloki_CurrLang.Sorted := True;
  result := vloki_CurrLang;

  //translate the TrayIconMenu
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  for i := 0 to loki_mainForm.TrayIconMenu.ItemsCount - 1 do
    loki_mainForm.TrayIconMenu.Items[i].Text := loki_translate(loki_mainForm.TrayIconMenu.Items[i].TagString);
  {$ENDIF}

end;


{*****************************************}
procedure loki_TranslationInitialization;
begin
  vloki_CurrLang := TALNVStringListU.Create;
  CustomTranslateProc := loki_translate;
end;

{***************************************}
procedure loki_Translationfinalization;
begin
  ALfreeandnil(vloki_CurrLang);
end;

initialization
  Win_UpdateGlobalInitializationList(loki_TranslationInitialization, 65);
  Win_UpdateGlobalFinalizationList(loki_Translationfinalization, 65);

end.
```

and everywhere in your code when you need a string, you simply do

```
StrINeed := loki_translate('theStrName');
```

notice also as we do CustomTranslateProc := loki_translate;
then it's could be compatible with label, but you must overload their loaded procedure (see alcinoe controls implementation, they did it)

i avoid Tlang because it's was very buggy for me, maybe this is not the case anymore in recent delphi version